# How to get the domain name of a embed code ( the best way )

Tags: php, preg-match

How to get the domain url of a embed code, i have 400k videos and i get the videos from many websites some of them its using iframe or object, what is the easy way and best way to get the domain of the embed code ?

Iframe Code Example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Embed Code Example:

```
<object width="990" height="750"> <param name="movie" value="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/"></param><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"` AllowScriptAccess="always" width="990" height="750"></embed></object>
```

So lets say $Domain_Embed = websites-test.com

Comment: Do they all contain http:// ?

Comment: yes ... how much i see yes ...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to parse the HTML code ([How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)), then extract the domains from the appropriate attributes. For example:

```
<?php

function getDomainFromEmbed($html, $all = false)
{
    $result = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    if (!empty($iframes)) {
        foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {
            if ($iframe->hasAttribute('src')) {
                $url = parse_url($iframe->getAttribute('src'), PHP_URL_HOST);
                if ($all) {
                    $result[] = $url;
                } else {
                    return $url;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $objects = $doc->getElementsByTagName('object');
    if (!empty($objects)) {
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object->hasAttribute('data')) {
                $url = parse_url($object->getAttribute('data'), PHP_URL_HOST);
                if ($all) {
                    $result[] = $url;
                } else {
                    return $url;
                }
            }

            $params = $object->getElementsByTagName('param');
            if (!empty($params)) {
                foreach ($params as $param) {
                    if ($param->hasAttribute('name') && $param->hasAttribute('value') && 'movie' === $param->getAttribute('name')) {
                        $url = parse_url($param->getAttribute('value'), PHP_URL_HOST);
                        if ($all) {
                            $result[] = $url;
                        } else {
                            return $url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $embeds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('embed');
    if (!empty($embeds)) {
        foreach ($embeds as $embed) {
            if ($embed->hasAttribute('src')) {
                $url = parse_url($embed->getAttribute('src'), PHP_URL_HOST);
                if ($all) {
                    $result[] = $url;
                } else {
                    return $url;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $all ? $result : null;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(getDomainFromEmbed('<iframe src="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no></iframe>'));
var_dump(getDomainFromEmbed('<object width="990" height="750"> <param name="movie" value="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/"></param><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"` AllowScriptAccess="always" width="990" height="750"></embed></object>'));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function getDomain($html) {
    preg_match('`<[^>]*src=["\'\s]?([^"^\'^\s]+)["\'\s][^>]*>`i', $html, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]))
        return parse_url($matches[1], PHP_URL_HOST);  
    return false;
}

$html = '<iframe src="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no></iframe>';
echo getDomain($html);

echo '<br />';

$html = '<object width="990" height="750"> <param name="movie" value="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/"></param><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.websites-test.com/video231/" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"` AllowScriptAccess="always" width="990" height="750"></embed></object>';
echo getDomain($html);
```

Of course instead of `echo getDomain($html)` you can put `$Domain_Embed = getDomain($html)` to assing it to your variable, just as you wanted. `$html` is the HTML code that contains these tags with `src` that you mentioned.

For multiple objects in the same `$html` you can change function to get array of results:

```
function getDomains($html) {
    $results = array();

    preg_match_all('`<[^>]*src=["\'\s]?([^"^\'^\s]+)["\'\s][^>]*>`i', $html, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]) && is_array($matches[1]))
        foreach($matches[1] as $match)
            $results[] = parse_url($match, PHP_URL_HOST);

    return empty($results) ? false : $results;
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r(getDomains($html), true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: i try ur code but the output is give me www.website-test.com or player.website-test.com or embed.website-test.com ... its any way to i get just website-test ? thanks

Comment: this regexp won't match: 1. the `src` attributes in `'` (single quotes) 2. the `src` attributes without any quotes - it's valid html(5); but will have a false match with any attribute, which ends with `src` & this regexp will only work in `<object>`s, whose has an `<embed>` fallback.

Comment: As this point i completely don't understand what you are trying to achieve... if you want just `website-test` always then why even parsing the HTML? My code returns everything that is found in every `src=" ... "` - you can change it, for example from `<[^>]*src="` to `<iframe [^>]*src="` to get only `src` results from `iframe` tags.

Comment: As @pozs mentioned before - my original regex would only match `src="..."` - i've just edited the answer and now it matches `src='...'` and `src=...` aswell.